# how to get current URL in SharePoint?

Tags: publishing-site

I am using SharePoint Server 2007 Enterprise with Windows Server 2008 Enterprise, and I am using publishing portal template. I am developing using VSTS 2008 + C# + .Net 3.5. I am using left navigation area (in SharePoint terms, it is also called current navigation area), and each item in the left navigation area maps to either a sub-site or a specific URL (i.e. clicks the item in left navigation area will display content of welcome page of the specific sub-site or the content of the specific URL in the main content area on the central area).

I want to know which URL is displayed on the main content area when an item in the left navigation area is clicked. Any samples to make a reference?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Could you tell a bit more on what part of the object model you are using?

If you are coding navigation api, theres other better approaches with the whole sitemap provider framework  (like `PortalSiteMapProvider`).

If you just want the current information in general, you can always use `SPContext.Current` to get hold of data like current web, site, list, listitem etc.

For example current user: `SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser` will return an `SPUser` object for current user.

To get current URL using `SPContext.Current` use

- `SPContext.Current.Web.Url` for absolute url
- `SPContext.Current.ServerRelativeUrl` for the relative position of web on site

Comment: What do you mean "what part of the object model"? Could you describe in more detail please?

Comment: Actually, I just create some child sites and by default in left navigation area of parent site, it contains link to each child site. When such link is clicked, I want to know which link is clicked. Any solutions?

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
SPContext.Current.ListItemServerRelativeUrl
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
string SiteUrl = SPContext.Current.Site.Url;//Get the url of current site
SPSite site = new SPSite(SiteUrl);//open the site with the url passed
SPWeb oWeb = site.OpenWeb();//open the web
```