# Getting SharePoint absolute site url

Tags: web-part

I need to get the current absolute url of my site from inside  code-behind. I tried 
SPContext.Current.Site.Url and get this error `Value does not fall within the expected range.`

The goal is to get this url: "http://myspweb.com/mypage.aspx" as result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolute : SPContext.Current.Web.Url

[Edit]

BTw there is simlar question already asked @ [how to get current URL in SharePoint?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/732/how-to-get-current-url-in-sharepoint)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Url` to get the full url which includes the page.

Answer (score 0):

i able to fix by doing:

```
SPContext.Current.ListItemServerRelativeUrl
```